# How can I get the source code of Idris standard library?

Tags: standard-library, idris

I'm intrested because I would like to inspect the definitions of built-in functions in Prelude.

I searched for it, but only found the precompiled files in ~/.cabal/share/idris...

Comment: Try the github repository: https://github.com/edwinb/Idris-dev/tree/master/lib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Vitus's comment I found the sources here:

https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/tree/master/libs

Answer (score 0):

For smaller queries there is also `:printdef` in the REPL

```
Idris> :printdef uncurry
uncurry : (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
uncurry f (a, b) = f a b
```